# can my ISP know which urls i'm visiting? If so then how to prevent it?

Tags: privacy, vpn, url, isp, microsoft-edge

i'm using latest version of microsoft edge browser on windows 10 PC and i'm in India. I use cloudeflare DNS. i Checked my browser security on https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/encrypted-sni/ and got this result - [image: cloudflare result]

So can my ISP know which urls i'm visiting? not just starting domain like "example.com" but full url like- "example.com/questions/ask"? Please tell me the answer for both http and https websites. If ISP can, then how do i prevent it? will using a VPN UDP connection prevent ISP from getting full urls I visit? or do i have to use VPN TCP connection?

Comment: Just use a VPN, your ISP will only know which VPN U r using, but not anything else assuming U Dont use any protocols that break Out of the VPN

Comment: Using a VPN shifts the information U "Tell" Ur ISP to the VPN, which may be even less private depending on the VPN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does SSL/TLS (https) hide the urls being accessed](/questions/7705/), [privacy - Which parts of URL is protected by HTTPS?](/questions/107941), [When using HTTPS, which part of domain is revealed to ISP?](/questions/171331), [What information can my ISP see when I visit a website?](/questions/107065), ....

Comment: so if i dont use vpn , isp can see full urls for both http and https websites?

Comment: yes, they can see both http and https websites urls, the s in https is for secure and that adds encryption for the content but does not hide the URL. The URL is not content it is the address.

Answer (score -1):

Lack of secure SNI means that you're broadcasting in plaintext to the server the FQDN of the site you want to which you'd like to connect.  This implies nothing about the rest of the URL.

You ask about HTTP in addition to HTTPS.  Realize that with HTTP, you are not receiving any of the benefits of that encryption & thus your entire conversation w/ the web server is unencrypted.

Comment: the question has nothing to do with encryption other than both https and http URLS won't be hidden from ISP without a VPN, he asked if the ISP can see which sites he visited. Other users answered it already in that using a VPN just switches it to the VPN having browsing history instead of the ISP.